# Java Inheritance subclass and superclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I found these questions online (university of waterloo exam study questions https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs125/S08/Resources/Exams/StudyQuestions/W07ExamReview/inheritance_questions.txt) but they were posted without any answers so I'd just like to know if I am correct or not.

1. Suppose the class named SportsCar is a subclass of a class called Automobile. Suppose the class Automobile has instance variables named speed, manufacturer, and numberOfCylinders. Will an object of the class SportsCar have instance variables named speed, manufacture, and numberOfCylinders?
2. Suppose the class named SportsCar is a subclass of a class called Automobile, and suppose the class Automobile has public methods named accelerate and addGas. Will an object of the class SportsCar have methods named accelerate and addGas? If so, do these methods have to perform the exact same actions in the class SportsCar as in the class Automobile?

1. True because a subclass inherits all of the superclass methods and
   variables
2. class SportsCar would have the method addGas but it wouldn't perform
   the 'exact' same action as the method in the class Automobile.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Question 2 is kind of tricky, you wouldn't have the methods in the subclass. However, you could still call them from the super class (making it the exact same).

Comment: ah, would the methods in the subclass have the same names as the methods in the superclass if it inherits it?

Comment: Yes, the same names. And the functionality would depend on if you override or not

Comment: Thanks, just a quick question since you're on here right now. Are instances of a subclass considered as instances of the superclass?

Comment: Yes, if you had a object `Vehicle` and `Car` was a subclass of it. You could have a list of `Vehicle` and `Car` would be considered a vehicle. To sum it up, this topic is largely dealing with polymorphism which is a "is a" relationship to an object. **Example** Car "IS A" Vehicle. Get it? :) @user3529827

Comment: Also look into the `instanceof()` method, which is a conditional statement used to compare the type of object

Answer (score 4):

1. in general no because it doesn't specify assess modifiers so that means if speed is private then SportCar will not have that property
2. Object of SportCar will have addGas and will do the same thing as instance of Automobile class unless the public method addGas is not Overridden in SportCar

Comment: Hm so I guess these questions would have many different answers depending on the circumstances. Subclasses cannot inherit private variables and methods right?

Comment: is it multiple choice question ? 
as you can see I didn't provide many answers

Comment: I posted my question with the url I got the questions from. I guess the questions just aren't worded perfectly

Comment: well, the wording of question is fine, and those are rather easy questions, they just contain trick,and I guess test your attention to details

Answer (score 0):

1) correct unless the instance variables are private

2) SportsCar could override the method, so it would not *have* to do exactly the same. SportsCar could even overload addGas to do something different based on the number and type of arguments to the method.

Answer (score 0):

1.
It depends on the implementation. If the access modifiers are private, the sub class (SportsCar) will not have 'access' to them, but this does not mean they don't exist. For example, SportsCar may  alter these values through a constructor as below.

```
public class Automobile {
    private int speed;
    private int manufacture;
    private int numberOfCylinders;

    public Automobile(int speed, int manufacture, int numberOfCylinders) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.manufacture = manufacture;
        this.numberOfCylinders = numberOfCylinders;
    }
}
```

Although Sportscar does not directly have access to them it can still modify the values depending on the implementation of Automobile.

```
public class SportsCar extends Automobile {

    public SportsCar() {
        super(5, 10, 20);
    }

}
```

2.
 Yes it will, and it can override them. But this is again dependent on the access modifiers of those methods in Automobile.

```
public class Automobile {
    public void addGas(){
        //adding gas
    }
}

public class SportsCar extends Automobile {
    @Override
    public void addGas() {
        // Do Something else
    }
}
```